# Modify Outlook Form Code programmatically

Tags: vba, outlook

How to programmatically get at outlook form code?

To clarify from one of the comments - Outlook form code is the VBA code that sits behind the form - it can be customised in the form design mode to do pretty much what the user needs to do.

Our product relies heavily on form code, but certain bits of it need to be customised per installation. We are looking for some way to automate this process, as we have upwards of 30 custom forms it is a tedious process to do it manually...:-)

Comment: do you mean how to get at the VBA behind the form ?

Comment: Thats the beastie - have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Cool I will have a look for you, but quick question why wouldn't you deploy all the code and test for the instalation type in the code ?

Comment: because what actaully needs modifiying is a public folder location and a connection string, rather than different chunks of code. But thanks again anyway...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a configuration file (use ReadFile etc)

Or put the configuration information in a "special" item in a public shared folder

You can also use the "Office Profile Wizard" to package it up with a custom vba module iwht the configuration information in that

You should never write out customised code, that is a big can of worms

Comment: +1 Upgrades would be a nightmare if the configuration wasn't separated.